# Self is not being captured in block

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, objective-c-blocks

I am having a problem where my block is not capturing and instance variables around it.  Here is the code:

```
__block NSArray *oldArray = self.savedArray;
viewController.block = ^(NSArray *array) {
    NSLog(@"array: %@", array);
    NSLog(@"oldArray: %@", oldArray); // CRASH
    NSLog(@"self: %@", self); // CRASH
};
```

My block is being called, but if I try to access self, or any instance variable, the app crashes.  Also, I tried to specifially call `__block` and its no help.

These is also no variables showing up in the variable view besides array(coming from block) and .block_descriptor. Thanks.

Comment: What does the property description for viewController.block look like (ie add it to your problem description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be your property definitions. I just coded and dumped the code you have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^b)(NSArray *a);
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    array = @[ @"1", @"2", @"3" ];

    __block NSArray *oldArray = array;
    b = ^void(NSArray *a) {
                NSLog(@"array: %@", a);
                NSLog(@"oldArray: %@", oldArray); // CRASH
                NSLog(@"self: %@", self); // CRASH
            };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ b(oldArray);}  );
}
2012-08-09 18:18:04.259 Searcher[49816:f803] array: (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
2012-08-09 18:18:04.260 Searcher[49816:f803] oldArray: (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
2012-08-09 18:18:04.261 Searcher[49816:f803] self: <ViewController: 0x6884550>
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue was I was not using ` dispatch_async'